# Can't add custom component to Intellij GUI form

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea

I have read the questions asked similar problem but it doesn't help me.My programs are all up to date and running with SDK 12 and Java Language Level 11.
I created an extended Jpanel and i want to add it to Gui form with Non-Palette but when i choose the class the name becomes red and nothing happens.
here is my extended Jpanel:

```
public class Panelback extends JPanel {
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:....bg.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

}

when i try to add it to GUI form and click ok nothing happens.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Vmm.png)

Comment: Please add some code example, illustrating the issue. Are you trying to add JScrollPane?

Comment: I added some details